# Converting ultrasound range to a Laser Scan

Tags: gazebo, navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my end of studies project, I have to make a robot that should do mapping and localization using only ultrasounds sensor. So for doing this i should convert sensor_msgs/LaserScan message to sensor_msgs/Range message.

My question: How can i do this ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264938/converting-ultrasound-range-to-a-laser-scan/) by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> If you already have a map, and want incorporate your sensor_msgs/Range in move_base, modify the existing obstacle_layer plugin to subscribe to a topic with message type sensor_msgs/Range instead of sensor_msgs/LaserScan.

Any reason to not just use [range_sensor_layer](http://wiki.ros.org/range_sensor_layer)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be knowing the angle(bearing) where your ultrasound sensors are positioned. Say you have 4 sensors placed in a circular fashion with a relative angular displacement of 90 degrees. You can use the above data to manipulate the fields in sensor_msgs/LaserScan. Append the range measured in the 'range' field. In this case the 'angle_increment' is 1.57 radians.

If you already have a map, and want incorporate your sensor_msgs/Range in move_base, modify the existing obstacle_layer plugin to subscribe to a topic with message type sensor_msgs/Range instead of sensor_msgs/LaserScan.

---

Originally posted by [Veera Ragav](https://answers.ros.org/users/29301/veera-ragav/) with karma: 240 on 2019-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Veera Ragav](https://answers.ros.org/users/29301/veera-ragav/) on 2019-05-13**:
Didn't know that existed! Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-13**:
I would in general refrain from suggesting users to edit files in released packages, unless there is a very good reason to do so.

**Comment by [Veera Ragav](https://answers.ros.org/users/29301/veera-ragav/) on 2019-05-13**:
I agree with you. Since the costmap layers are plugins, one may hack an existing layer plugin and name it whatever they would like to. That's why I suggested that.